# Java 8 - Inferring generic return type with lambdas

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I am trying to preserve the Generic type information from the return type of a lambda expression across some higher-order-functions in Java 8. I have simplified my actual code down to this test case. The problem is not what I expect the code to do exactly, but rather than I expect the generic type(s) `R` to be inferred as `java.lang.String` and carried through the function calls.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class AdamTest {

    public final static void main(final String args[]) {
        final AdamTest adamTest = new AdamTest();

        final String s = adamTest.thing2(7).apply(i -> i.toString());
        System.out.println(s);
    }


    private <R> R fn1(final Function<Integer, R> op) {
        return op.apply(10);
    }

    private <R> Function<Function<Integer, R>, R> thing2(final Integer val) {
        return fn1(i -> new Function<Function<Integer, R>, R>() {
                @Override
                public R apply(Function<Integer, R> op) {
                    return op.apply(val * i);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

At the moment this code does not compile because of this line `final String s = adamTest.thing2(7).apply(i -> i.toString());`. I think I have something subtly wrong with my type bounds, as the compiler does not seem to be able to infer the return type of `thing2(7).apply` and reports `Object` rather than `String` which I was hoping for.

How do I get the generic type bounds correct so that the correct return type i.e. `java.lang.String` is ***inferred*** by the compiler?

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: The compiler "evaluates" the expression from left to right; The problem occurs at `adamTest.thing2(7)`. The compiler doesn't look at the `.apply` to figure out the type, and without that it isn't possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? This is completely unclear.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLeonhard that is the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Why are you mixing lambdas and inner classes that inconsistent way? Why not implementing `thing2` as `return fn1(i -> op -> op.apply(val * i));`?

Comment: that was already suggested in the answer from @assylias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already said, those statements are evaluated from left to right.

To force the compiler to use the correct type, you can simply write it as

```
final String s = adamTest.<String>thing2(7).apply(String::valueOf);
```

EDIT: As per the comments, the lambda expression can be substituted by a method reference (looks cleaner).

Comment: Also, you can replace the method call to i.toString() with a method reference.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak Unfortunately that cannot be done. The class `Integer` defines two methods named both `toString`: one static method [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) and one non-static method [`Integer.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--). The compiler cannot distinguish between them if using the method reference `Integer::toString`.

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose this is the solution I came to myself, but somehow I really expected better inferencing from the compiler and so felt that I had made a mistake in my generics, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose `String::valueOf` on the other hand is not ambiguous

Comment: If you have trouble with `Integer::toString` being ambiguous, just use `Object::toString`. That’s the same method…

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that it can be fixed without casts (maybe someone knows better). An alternative is to split your statements in two lines:

```
Function<Function<Integer, String>, String> thing2 = adamTest.thing2(7);
final String s = thing2.apply(i -> i.toString());
```

Also note that `thing2` can be simplified:

```
private <R> Function<Function<Integer, R>, R> thing2(final Integer val) {
  return fn1(i -> (op -> op.apply(val * i)));
}
```

Comment: I would split it into two statements if there was an `auto` type in Java, but as there isn't I prefer to use the generic cast suggested by @Seelenvirtuose. I do like the simplification though, thanks.