# Why Java fails to infer the return type of nested lambda function in some situations?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-stream

I noticed some weird behaviors with the type inference mechanism when using nested lambda functions and generic types in Java. (I was using Java 8, but newer versions seem to have similar results.) Consider the following code:

```
Stream<Stream<Integer>> stream = ...; // may be meaningless; just as an example

// Guess the reported types!
stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> i));
stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> ""));
```

In fact, both mapping expressions get **`Stream<Stream<Object>>`**, *not* `Stream<Stream<Integer>>` and `Stream<Stream<String>>`. It may not be explained as Java failing to infer the return types, as the second one's type is obvious.
Even more, the most curious thing is that, when something is added in like:

```
stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((Integer i) -> i)); // prepend parameter type
stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> i).findAny().get()); // cascade any method
stream = stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> i)); // assign to Stream<Stream<Integer>>
```

The return type of the inner lambdas will be infered as **`Integer`** now, though nothing *actually* changed with them (but the third one can provide more type information which might help inferring). How confusing.

So why would such things happen? I have read a related topic [Java 8 - Inferring generic return type with lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898168/java-8-inferring-generic-return-type-with-lambdas) but it didn't help much and I was still quite unclear.

**A late update:** This problem is caused by an outdated Eclipse which did not conform to the language standard. There is no problem in the code.

Comment: `Stream<Stream<Integer>> x = stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> i));` compiles for me on Java 17. How did you find that the type is `Stream<Stream<Object>>`?

Comment: This also compiles after testing on Java 8. However, without assignment it will remain `Stream<Stream<Object>>`. Therefore `stream.map((inner) -> inner.map((i) -> i)).forEach((inner) -> inner.forEach((i) -> i.intValue()));` will fail. I'll clarify it in the question.

Comment: `Stream.of(Stream.of(1,2), Stream.of(3)).map(inner->inner.map(i->i)).forEach(inner->inner.forEach(i->System.out.println(i.intValue())));` works just fine for me with Java 11. No compiler errors, even if I assign the intermediate result to a new variable of type `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`. Haven't tested with Java 8.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/OGgqcO)

Comment: @knittl It fails on Java 8. Seems to be a problem of this old version.

Comment: Can share the code which fails (*or its obfuscated/simplified version which also fails to compile*) ?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Just as the comment before. Error will be `intValue() is undefined for the type Object`. Initial value of `stream` can be anything legal like `Stream.of(Stream.of(1))`.

Comment: No, I was talking about the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not about some code that we can compile only in our heads. For instance, the code posted [by @knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184631/why-java-fails-to-infer-the-return-type-of-nested-lambda-function-in-some-situat#comment130978560_74184631) compiles and runs fine.

Comment: All cases working with `openjdk version "1.8.0_345"`, no problems detected.

Comment: @josejuan Problem solved. You reminded me that it may not be the problem of Java environment. After installing a newer IDE, type inference works perfectly now. Seems that outdated versions of Eclipse cannot infer types backwards correctly (though I don't understand why a problem of IDE could affect compiling, as it also failed if I proceed running with false "errors"). Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler. Keep that in mind for the future. If you have problem with the compiler in Eclipse, don’t forget to mention that you’re using Eclipse. Or re-check that you can reproduce the issue with `javac` first.

Comment: I’m voting to close my question because its problem is caused by an outdated IDE which did not conform to its language standard, and is not a problem in code.